# like system not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have used ajax to load the rating system on my page but it is showing me rating for only 1 post not for other posts

[image]

[image]

as you can see from the above images it is showing rating for 1 post and not for another and i am sure that my database is filled for both posts

my ajax

```
<script>
//where $mypostid is already set in my file
function load'.$mypostid.'()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("echoresult'.$mypostid.'").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    parameters="id='.$mypostid.'";
    xmlhttp.open("POST","like.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(parameters);
}
window.addEventListener("load",load'.$mypostid.');
</script>
```

my like.php

```
<?php
$connection30=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123456789','register');
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{$postid=$_POST['id'];
$queryselect=mysqli_query($connection30,"select * from likes where postid='$postid'");
while($rowselect=mysqli_fetch_array($queryselect))
{
    $countlikes=$rowselect['likes'];
    $countdislikes=$rowselect['dislikes'];
    $likepercentage=($countlikes/($countlikes+$countdislikes))*100;
    echo ceil($likepercentage).'% people liked this';
}}
?>
```

and my div element for displaying rating

```
<div id="echoresult'.$mypostid.'"></div>
```

Comment: As I see it, your javascript  function load'.$mypostid.'() also need to be written  again and again  for all posts in the loop. If you are not doing that, then it will be available only once for the first post.

Comment: but i am not getting idea on how to write again and again for all posts and post numbers may increase to more than 1000